# How can i sum numbers from span tag when click input checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need when select checkbox to sum all number as total cost .I write code but it's will be very long and not professional to do all status if user checked one or 2 ,4,all . this html code

```
<div class="features">
             <h3>مميزات الكورس والسكن  </h3>
                 <hr class="style17">
              <br><br><br>

        <div class="feature-details">


          <h4>خيارات السكن </h4>
            <div class="row skn-block">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div>  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="individ-price" id="individ-price-check" onclick="individPrice();"><label> 
                    سكن فردى</label>
                    <span id="individ-price"><span id="num1">400</span>$</span>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="family-price" id="family-price-check" onclick="familyPrice()"><label>سكن عائلى </label>
                     <span id="family-price"><span id="num2">500</span>$</span>
                 </div>

            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="special-price" id="special-price-check" onclick="specialPrice()"><label>سكن خاص</label>
                    <span id="special-price"><span id="num3">500</span>$</span>
                </div>

            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="included-price" id="include-price-check" onclick="includePrice()"><label>سكن متضمن </label>
                     <span id="include-price"><span id="num4">500</span>$</span>
                 </div>

            </div>
          </div>


         </div>

           <div class="feature-details">


          <h4>هل تحتاج توصيل من المطار </h4>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="fromair-check" onclick="fromair();"><label> 
                    نعم</label></div>
            </div>     
                <span id="fromair">التكلفة :
                    <span id="num5"> 300</span>$</span>
          </div>

          <h4>هل تحتاج توصيل إلى المطار </h4>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="toair-check" onclick="toair();"><label> 
                    نعم</label></div>
            </div>

             <span id="toair">التكلفة : 
                 <span id="num6">300</span>$
                </span>
             </div>


            </div>

          <div class="feature-details">
          <h4>هل تحتاج   إلى التامين  </h4>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="policy-check" onclick="policy();"><label> 
                    نعم</label></div>
            </div>

                 <span id="policy">التكلفة :
                     <span id="num7"> 300</span>$</span>
          </div>    
            </div>

          <div class="feature-details">
          <h4> ارسال الأوراق باستخدام ال   
                     HDL</h4>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="hdl-check" onclick="hdlfun();"><label> 
                    نعم</label></div>
            </div>

              <span id="hdl">التكلفة :
                  <span id="num8">200</span>$</span>  
          </div>    
            </div>

                 <div class="feature-details">

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
               <label>رسوم التسجيل </label>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">

               <label>التكلفة :
                   100$ </label>

                </div>
            </div>

          </div>    
                <button class="save-send" onclick="senddetail()"> حفظ وارسال</button>
            </div>
```

this my js code

```
 <script>
    var chkbasicindivid = document.getElementById("individ-price-check");
    var chkbasicspecial = document.getElementById("special-price-check"); 
    var chkbasicinclude = document.getElementById("include-price-check");
    var chkbasicfamily  = document.getElementById("family-price-check");
    var chkpolicy       = document.getElementById("policy-check");
    var chkfromair      = document.getElementById("fromair-check");
    var chktoair        = document.getElementById("toair-check");
    var chkhdl          = document.getElementById("hdl-check");

       function senddetail(){

                 if ((chkbasicspecial.checked)&(chkpolicy.checked)&(chkfromair.checked)&(chktoair.checked)&(chkhdl.checked)){
                     var totalprice =0;
                     alert((parseInt(($("#num3")).text()))+(parseInt(($("#num5")).text()))+(parseInt(($("#num6")).text()))+(parseInt(($("#num7")).text()))+(parseInt(($("#num8")).text())));


                      };
```

I need good way to get good solution.

Comment: Add common handler e.g class to all these elements (radio button and checkbox). Add click event to common class handler and on every click (check/uncheck)  event add the total cost/remove cost.

Comment: Why are you checking to see if all of the checkboxes are checked before calculating the total? Seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: @ganesh I do another action with id for each one not like other

Comment: you can use Class instead of id and also if possible try to add the price tag as data-price-attr to the checkbox/radio elements so that when you click on it you can just get the value from attribute.

Comment: @ganesh thanks , could you give me simple example

Comment: Try to add data-price attribute to radio/checkbox                                                                                     
 <input type="radio" name="gender" class="product-item" data-price="400" value="individ-price" id="individ-price-check">                                                             $('.product-item').click(function(){ totalsum += $(this).attr('data-price');  });     Hope it helps

Comment: @ganesh The price is displayed : none and User show it only when check [checkbox or radio button] so this method will not be suitable .Can i display none for price with this method and show it only when user click each input?